# How to properly convert query into DateTime in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my app, I am trying to grab a date from the database and compare it against local time. Right now I am getting an error when I am converting to date incorrectly.

I have tried:

- `Convert.ToDateTime()`
- `DateTime.ParseExact()`

My code:

```
string time = "Select top(1) DATE from SERVICE order by DATE desc"; 

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(time, connection);
connection.Open();

using (SqlDataReader timereader = timecommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (timereader.Read())
    {
        if (DateTime.ParseExact(time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null).AddMinutes(10) > currenttime)
        {
            // code
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

I am hoping when I retrieve this value from the database, I can convert it into a proper `datetime` value and compare against local time and run other code after that.

At the moment I am just getting this error:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

I'm probably just dumb and missing something obvious..

Comment: What does the value of `time` look like when you're debugging?

Comment: The variable `time` in your code appears to be a SQL query rather than a date string. I'm guessing what you really intended was to use the _result_ of that query rather than the query itself - see Caius' answer below for the simplest way to achieve that.

Comment: Oh okay. yea i am meaning to use the result instead of the query. and okay thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your query selects a single value. Use ExecuteScalar and cast it to a DateTime (it's already a DateTime, but boxed inside an `object`):

```
string time = "Select top(1) DATE from SERVICE order by DATE desc"; 

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(time, connection);
connection.Open();
DateTime d = (DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
```

After you do this, and before you embark on some long mission of this protracted way of getting data out of a database, converting it to objects for use in your app etc, take a look at least at an ORM called Dapper, if not Entity Framework. Dapper's basically what you're doing now, but it auto converts your queries to objects and back and saves a lot of tedious code. With Dapper it'd look more like:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connstr"))
{   
  var d = connection.QuerySingle<DateTime>("SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM ...");
}
```

Yes, it's not much of a saving over what you have now, right? But what if you have a list of Order that themselves have 20 properties:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connstr"))
{   
  var orders = connection.Query<Order>("SELECT * FROM order WHERE customerID = @custid", new {custid = 123}).ToList();
}
```

Orders is now a list of Order objects for customer 123, parameterized, injection safe, quick and a one liner to read and populate your orders; doing that in a datareader is going to take at least 25 lines of boring code

http://dapper-tutorial.net and spend 2 minutes reading; I'll lay bets you'll be glad you did

Comment: Huh that is interesting. Ive never heard of Dapper. Probably because im fairly new. But i will definitely look into it!

Answer (score 1):

Just try to read the value as a **proper, native** `DateTime` type like this (assuming that the `DATE` column in SQL Server is in fact a `DATETIME` or similar datatype - not a string - hopefully!):

```
using (SqlDataReader timereader = timecommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (timereader.Read())
    {
        // just read the DateTime value as such
        DateTime dt = timereader.GetDateTime(0);

        // then do whatever you need to do with this DateTime value .....
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```